# reading golang websocket returns random bytes

Tags: go, websocket

My program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"

    "github.com/gobwas/ws"
)

func HandleConn(conn net.Conn) {
    for {
        header, err := ws.ReadHeader(conn)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        buf := make([]byte, header.Length)
        _, err = io.ReadFull(conn, buf)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(buf)
        fmt.Println(string(buf))
    }
}

func main() {
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:8080")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for {
        conn, err := ln.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        _, err = ws.Upgrade(conn)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        go HandleConn(conn)
    }
}
```

I do in browser console:

```
let socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8080")
socket.send("Hello world")
```

I see random bytes in the my terminal. Each call to `socket.send("Hello world")` return different bytes. But the length of the byte array is always equal to the length of the string. Where does golang get these random bytes? How can I fix this? My program is an example from the docs.

Comment: I'm not sure what docs you're referring to, or which websocket library you're using, but none of the popular ones have you directly accessing a `net.Conn`. The only one that has an `Update` function (gorilla) accepts an HTTP request & response, not a `net.Conn`, and doesn't return a `net.Conn`. Can you provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example?

Comment: @Adrian I use: https://github.com/gobwas/ws. Docs: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gobwas/ws. I use tcp in my code because it is necessary for Zero-copy upgrade: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gobwas/ws#readme-zero-copy-upgrade

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to not use the `wsutil` you need to unmask the payload:

```golang
buff := make([]byte, header.Length)
_, err = io.ReadFull(conn, buff)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
if header.Masked {
    ws.Cipher(buff, header.Mask, 0)
}
fmt.Println(string(buff))
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that you should set `header.Masked = false` if you reuse the header to write to the client (e.g. `ws.WriteHeader(conn, header)`) as per https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-5.1